# Conda returns HTTP connection failed error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, anaconda, conda, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed Anaconda on my Linux VM.
running `conda update conda` returns the following error :

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64'
```

Using `-v` to see the detailes shows that I have the `SSL` error :

```
conda update -v conda

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /pkgs/main/linux-64/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /pkgs/r/linux-64/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json
```

Even after setting SSL verification to false, `conda config --set ssl_verify false`, I have still the same error.

Comment: Too much unknowns. But my guess is that you either configured a proxy and this configuration is wrong, that you have some antivirus in the VM host inferring with the traffic or that there is some TLS intercepting proxy in the network inferring with the traffic. Not that ignoring certificate validation like you've tried will only help if the problem is actually the certificate validation - which is not the case here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich This is a company VM on Azure and yes that is using a proxy. I have requested the *.anaconda.com to be whitelisted that I could have access. (as well as the *.anaconda.org, pypi.org). The VM is able to connect to internet so the proxy set up is correct and it is done by IT. What is your proposal ? what should I check to find our where is the error ?

Comment: *"The VM is able to connect to internet so the proxy set up is correct and it is done by IT."* - there are no generic proxy settings. Conda will likely have it's own proxy settings and these might be wrong. Just because "the VM" (i.e. some specific program inside the VM) can connect somehow (HTTP, HTTPS?) to the internet does not mean that conda  can.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, What is your proposal ? what should I check to find out where is the error ?

Comment: So is there a specific proxy set for conda? Is this value maybe `https://...` instead of `http://...` because this is a common error that users believe that a HTTPS proxy needs to have a `https://` URL. Check `https_proxy` environment variable for example.

Comment: both `echo $http_proxy` and `echo $https_proxy` returns the same output like `http://proxy.dmz1.something:3128/` and this is the only proxy setup, nothing specifically for conda

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230816/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-user9112767).